# How to append state variables' value into a string in AMP pages?

Tags: amp-html

I have an AMP-state :

```
<amp-state id="Form">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
    "id" :"1",
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

I want to dynamically make the redirect URL with the value of id, and I am doing like this:

```
<a [href] = "myWebsite.com/{{Form.id}}" href="#" />
```

Sample URL: `myWebsite.com/1002`

But instead of getting the value of the state variable `id`, I am getting:

```
myWebiste.com/%7B%7BForm.id%7D%7D
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following will fix your problem :

```
<a [href] = " 'myWebsite.com/' + Form.id " href="#" />
```

you don't need the braces here.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/7399), at the moment it's only possible to set the values for global variables via `AMP.setState` but not for variables declared inside `amp-state`.

> Example:   `AMP.setState(foo=123)` -> is working
>
> `AMP.setState(myAmpState.foo=123)` where
>
> ```
> <amp-state id="myAmpState">
>       <script type="application/json">
>       {
>           "foo": "234"
>       }
> .....
> ```
>
> is not working.

Current workaround is setting default variables.